# SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to setup `Cppyy` from [this](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/repositories.html#building-from-source-1) website and then,
I get this error in this step.

```
python setup.py egg_info
```

To replicate, please clone [this repository](https://github.com/wlav/cppyy-backend.git), switch to the directory and run.

```
python setup.py egg_info
```

Im trying this out in *windows command prompt*.
I am new  to programming in general. Please try to keep the explanations simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `--use-pep517` flag to the command when installing a package:

```
 pip install mypackage --use-pep517
```